# jQuery/Firefox: open new window and change content (head and body)

Tags: jquery, firefox, popup, window.open

I want to open a popup window with `window.open` and then changing the whole content of the window.

In IE and Chrome the following is working well, but **not** in **firefox**.

```
var Window= window.open("blanko.htm", "Win", "width=" + _iWidth + ",height=" + _iHeight + ",resizable=yes,left=" + iLeft + ",top=" + iTop + ",toolbar=1");
var Header = "<head><link rel='Stylesheet' href='CSS.css' type='text/css' /><style type='text/css'>td,th{font-size:11px;font-family:Arial;}body{font-family:Arial;font-size:12px;}</style></head>";
var Body = "<body><div>new Content</div></body>";
```

First Try:

```
 $(Window.document).ready(function () {
        $(Window.document.head).append(Header);
        $(Window.document.body).append(Body);
    });
```

Second Try:

```
$(Window.document).ready(function () {
        $(Window.document).html(Header + Body);
});
```

etc.

Everything I try in this way works in IE and Chrome, but in Firefox the content is loading and after one second it is replaced by the site given in the `window.open` parameter (blanko.htm).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with pure Javascript here is a very simple solution:

```
var mynewWindow = window.open("", "Win", "width=" + _iWidth + ",height=" + _iHeight + ",resizable=yes,left=" + iLeft + ",top=" + iTop + ",toolbar=1");

        mynewWindow.document.write(
           '<html>' + 
             '<head>' + 
               '<title>' + myTitle + '</title>' + 
               '<link rel="Stylesheet" href="CSS.css" type="text/css" />' +
               //print on screen style
               '<style media="screen"> your CSS here </style>'+
               //Optional: print on printer style
               '<style media="print"> your CSS here </style>'+
             '</head>' + 
             '<body> <div>new Content</div> </body>' + 
           '</html>'
        );
```

Hope that helped

(This should work with all major internet browsers)